# Nested collapsibles break jQuery Mobile layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I tried to nest a collapsible inside a listview but it breaks my layout: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17844821/zeug/jquery_mobile_collapsible_break.jpg

What's wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>jQMail</title> 
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>jQMail</h1>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#inbox">INBOX</a></li>
        <li><a href="#inbox">Sent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#inbox">Trash</a></li>
        <li>
            <h3>Archive</h3>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="d">
                <h3>By date</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">
                    <li><a href="#m2010">2010</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#m2009">2009</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#m2008">2008</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should the parent <li> be collapsible instead?

Comment: @orolo Either that or I simply want the left and right part of the collapsible container to be not broken (see red arrows in the screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS imported from `jquery.mobile.min.css` applies a margin

```
.ui-collapsible-content {
  margin: 0 -8px;
  ...
```

You can override it with CSS, adding `margin` on `.ui-collapsible-content` style, like that :

```
.ui-collapsible-content {
    margin: -9px 0 0 0 ;
}
```

**Edit** : If you just want to only impact this component, you can add an `id` on the parent div, and specify the CSS path. For example :

```
<div id="dateListView" data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="d"> ...
```

with this CSS

```
div#dateListView.ui-collapsible div.ui-collapsible-content {
    margin: -9px 0 0 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Hm, that looks like a very "hackish" solution to me. Setting a negative margin value isn't very flexible as well. Isn't there a smoother, more elegant solution without overriding css? I mean there must be a way to acomplish what I am trying to do the "proper official" way.

Comment: I see what you mean but jQuery plays with CSS margin in order to have a good look and feel. For example the `.ui-collapsible-content` has a negative margin. This is typically a CSS issue, I advise you to correct it using CSS...

Comment: I guess you're right. I tried your trick and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fine if this answer satisfies your request... Will I win my first bounty? ;)